# Can I use a Thunderbolt 3 cable in place of a USB-C cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, dock, thunderbolt

I need to connect my MacBook to a USB-C dock but the included USB-C cable isn't long enough. I have a several longer Thunderbolt 3 cables, so I wanted to know if I could connect the USB-C dock via a Thunderbolt 3 cable?

I realize I cannot do it the other way around, but I have never seen anywhere where it said you cannot do it the way I am proposing.

I'm using the [CalDigit USB-C Dock](http://caldigit.com/usb-3-1-usb-c-dock/).

Answer (score 3):

Since [Thunderbolt 3](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/blog/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-does-it-all) is a "multi-plexing" of several signals *including* USB 3.1, you can use a Thunderbolt 3 cable in place of a USB-C cable.   As you stated, it can't be done the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, while the TB3 cable will send *some* signals to the USB-C dock, it won't send a video signal on my CalDigit USB-C Dock. From what I can tell is all USB ports work, charging working, but it appears nothing else works.

Comment: Couple of things - 1) this is not what you originally asked; you asked about USBC, with no mention of video.  2) a TB cable ***must*** send video otherwise you wouldn't be able to daisy chain displays.  Is your dock dropping the signal?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Allan. I said it was a USB-C dock, which in all known cases, includes video. Regardless, any and all TB3 cables I tried won't send a video signal from the Mac to the USB-C dock. Also, when I connect the USB-C cable, the Mac makes makes a chime sound. Connecting the TB3 cable, no sound is made.